Why cannot I use pnpm?



I have installed volta and configured environment variable. As you can see, node -v and npm -v works. But why can't pnpm be used? What can I do to use pnpm? Did I do something wrong?
I have installed volta and configured environment variable. As you can see, node -v and npm -v works. But why can't pnpm be used? What can I do to use pnpm? Did I do something wrong?

how have you installed pnpm? Did you use volta to install pnpm? You can try to install pnpm using one of the other recommended installation methods: https://pnpm.io/installation
The easiest way to install pnpm is using corepack

OK,  now I know the reason. The .exe and .cmd are not for straight uses. We still need to run volta install pnpm.
